# Standard deviation of sample mean differences used as the basis for calculating standard error of the two samples

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, standard-error, group-differences, t-distribution

I came across this problem in the [OpenIntro Statatistics (it is very free)](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php) textbook: 
[image: Problem in the textbook]

Now, in calculating the t-statistic for the difference of means, the same book shows that the Standard Error in question is derived as follows:

$SE_{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}} = \sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}$

I calculated this (SE = 3338.11), used it to calculated the t-score (0.55, df = 9).
With this I got a giant p-value concluded that results are very strongly in favor of $H_0$ ($H_0:\bar{x}_{diff} = 0; H_A:\bar{x}_{diff} \neq 0$).

When I checked the answer with the book, the book had clearly used the standard deviation of the Diff. distribution and, apparently, used the simple formula:

$SE_{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}} = \frac{s_{Diff.}}{\sqrt{n}}$

This meant that the answer was completely different as $p < 0.01$

**My questions are:**

- Why do the two methods makes such different results?
- Did I make a mistake in assuming independence?
- What are the ways to not make this mistake again?